# Python whitespace and non breaking space not matched in regex

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace a date / time with a regex in Python into * signs. The challenge is in the HTML source there's a `&nbsp;` character. I don't know how to catch it with Python

My HTML source code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
  <body leftmargin="15" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <table summary="" width="97%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">U heeft gezocht met</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%">Postcode:</td>
          <td colspan="2">9999 ZZ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Huisnummer:</td>
          <td colspan="2">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"> </td>
          <td class="r">20-11-2017                                  11:51:01</td>
        </tr>        
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

My python regex code

```
def _fixhtml(self, filename):
    regex_datetime = r'<div align="right">\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}</div>'
    subst_datetime = '<div align="right">**-**-**** **:**</div>'
    regex_datetime1 = r'<td class="r">\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}\xa0\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}</td>'
    subst_datetime1 = '<td class="r">**-**-**** **:**:**</td>'

    out_fname = filename + ".tmp"
    with open(filename) as f:
        out = open(out_fname, "w")
        for line in f:
            line = re.sub(regex_datetime, subst_datetime, line)
            line = re.sub(regex_datetime1, subst_datetime1, line)
            out.write(line)
        out.close()
    os.remove(filename)
    os.rename(out_fname, filename)
```

I tried multiple combination like \S\s+ and the last one I found to 'catch' the `&nbsp;` character, but it won't match.

Comment: You need to write `&nbsp;` as string!

Comment: don't parse html with regex - it's BAD practice

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ example showing the issue. (Something someone could just copy-paste and run to reproduce it.)

Comment: @glibdud I added a working example of the issue. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Vinnio It's not the HTML that was incomplete, it's the processing code. How do you get the HTML into a Python variable? How exactly do you apply the regex? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @glibdud included the python code I use.